# CSS color transform changes border color

Tags: css, css-transitions

So I have this button on my website that has grey background, red border, and red text, and I want it so that when you hover over it the background turns red, and text turns white, border doesn't change. What happens is when you take your mouse off the button the border color becomes white, and then once the transition is over it quickly goes back to red.

Usually I know this code should work, but I think since I'm using transition it doesn't. Here's the full CSS code:

```
#leftWebsiteTitle a:link{
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    padding:7px 10px 7px 14px;
    margin:37px;

    font-family:graduate;
    color:#C83434;  
    border:3px solid #C83434;
    background:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:44px;
    -webkit-transition: color 300ms, background 300ms;
    -moz-transition: color 300ms, background 300ms;
    -o-transition: color 300ms, background 300ms;
    -ms-transition: color 300ms, background 300ms;
    transition: color 300ms, background 300ms;

}
#leftWebsiteTitle a:visited{
    color:#C83434;  
    text-decoration:none;
}

#leftWebsiteTitle a:hover{
    color:#FFF;
    border:3px solid #C83434;
    background:#C83434;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition: color 100ms, background 100ms;
    -moz-transition: color 100ms, background 100ms;
    -o-transition: color 100ms, background 100ms;
    -ms-transition: color 100ms, background 100ms;
    transition: color 100ms, background 100ms;

}
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?
Thanks!

Comment: The hover property will allow it to change back to the original after the item is no longer being hovered over.

Comment: Does this code only transition once, and then go back to the original without moving the mouse off of the link?   Also, does it continuously loop?

Comment: Not sure if you understood the problem correctly. It DOES change back to it, but for the duration of the transition border becomes white, which it shouldn't since I never try to change the border's color.

Comment: Is this correct or does it have the problem?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zFvGL
I am testing with chrome, and the border DOES NOT turn white during the transition.  Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: that is correct. did you change something or is it the code I had?

Comment: Code you had already.  I just put in some simple html.  I used EXACTLY the CSS you had.  One thing that does confuse me though is why you have your transitions in your normal link id code instead of only in Hover?

Comment: huh, that is really weird. I'll check the rest of the code. Thanks tho!

Comment: Oh, oops.  I didn't really change anything, but I did make your transition times to 1000 instead of 100.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43805/discussion-between-okush69-and-camdixon)

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem to be not in the code provided above. I had transition applied to the div that was containing that button, and that's what was interfering with this transition. Once I removed that it worked fine.